# Intel 8080: Increment address

Tags: assembly, intel-8080

I am doing my homework and in the last example I don't really understand what to do: (sorry for my bad English, hope you will understand)

**Example**: define 'var' variable. In memory from address, which is stored in H, L as 16-bit number, fill number of bytes in 'var' with value 3. So, to the address by H, L insert the value of 3 with register M. Then the address in registers H, L increment by 1 (you need to use ADD or ADC, because INR does not set CF). Repeat this 'var' times.

My program looks like this now, but how can I continue? Thanks

```
var     db
        lda var
        mov b,a
loop:   dcr b
                     ; Code here
        jnz loop
end:    hlt
```

Comment: @rcgldr This actually won't work, because emulator I use, doesn't support 'add reg,num' instruction, only simple 'add reg' and also 'set' instruction.

Comment: Use | INX H |, which will increment HL .